# How to align image with text in a table ? (jquery datatable sort image with text in table header)

Tags: css

I am using jQUery DataTable plugin, I have html table and the table header text and the image to sort are not aligning.

**How it looks**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqgz9.png **(I want the arrow and the text to be in same line horizontally). How to do it ?**

I have uploaded the below code on jsfiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/icyborg7/9DTcT/

**HTML Code**

```
<th class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="contacts_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 73.7667px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="S.No.: activate to sort column descending">

<div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">S.No.<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span>

</div>
</th>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/assets_dev/jquery-ui/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png");
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-n {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
.ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/assets_dev/jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}
.ui-icon {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
.ui-icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
* {
    outline: medium none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/9DTcT/2/

```
.ui-icon {

display: inline-block;

}
```

hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: perfect, though I don't want to edit jquery core file, is there any other way I can do this too ?

Comment: mmm.. it could work to add an extra class to this element and give that class this `display: inline-block;`